# eval getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, string, eval

Iam using eval function to insert values of corresponding narration ,I am stuck on this below code kindly help me to get rid of this error

```
var HeadMsg="ON CHEQUE CLEARANCE OF";
var pHead=" "+"PRINCIPAL COMPONENT";
var iHead=" "+"INTEREST COMPONENT";
var eHead=" "+"ON EMI NO";
var lHead=" "+"LOAN NO";

var $pricipal=" "+"1500";
var $interest=" "+"1000";
var $emino=" "+"1";
var $loanno=" "+"SCL2018000000000000000048";



var narr=HeadMsg +lHead + $loanno +pHead+ $pricipal +iHead+ $interest +eHead+ $emino;
var out=eval(narr);
console.log(out);
```

**OUTPUT with error**

> ON CHEQUE CLEARANCE OF LOAN NO SCL2018000000000000000048 PRINCIPAL COMPONENT 1500 INTEREST COMPONENT 1000 ON EMI NO 1
>   with
>
> VM512:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: What is `+` in front of `pHead, iHead` etc? `" "+"PRINCIPAL COMPONENT";` is not a valid string

Comment: `eval(narr)` will try to **interpret** the content of `narr` using the Javascript language compiler. It should be obvious that `"ON CHEQUE CLEARANCE OF LOAN (etc)"` is *not valid Javascript at all*.

Comment: what is the expected result / what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @lucascaro my expected output should be ON CHEQUE CLEARANCE OF LOAN NO SCL2018000000000000000048 PRINCIPAL COMPONENT 1500 INTEREST COMPONENT 1000 ON EMI NO 1

Comment: @PeterB kindly give some possible way to assign run time values on narration ?

Comment: @brk kinldy correct the narr line ?

Comment: @PeterB Above narration format is coming from template ,while execution i need to pick this current value for these variable eval and submit to another api

Comment: @brk `+` in front of `pHead ,iHead` space before that word

Comment: @vijoy you don't need to do `" " + "ON...` you can put the space in the string like so: `" ON CHEQUE...`

Answer (score 0):

What are you even using eval for? Just console.log(narr) would give you the output you need.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

[You shouldn't ever use eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

if what you want is to output the given string you can simply `console.log` the string:

```
var narr=HeadMsg +lHead + $loanno +pHead+ $pricipal +iHead+ $interest +eHead+ $emino;
console.log(narr);
```

or simply use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and output the message:

```js
const principal="1500";
const interest="1000";
const emino="1";
const loanno="SCL2018000000000000000048";

console.log(`ON CHEQUE CLEARANCE OF LOAN NO ${loanno} PRINCIPAL COMPONENT ${principal} INTEREST COMPONENT ${interest} ON EMI NO ${emino}`);
```